# warning messages when trying to run glmer in r

Tags: r, lme4

Currently I'm trying to rerun an old data analysis, binomial glmer model, (from early 2013) on the latest version of R and lme4, because I don't have the old versions of R and lme4 anymore. However, I experience similar warning messages as previous threads by dmartin and carine (first warning message) and other threads outside stack overflow (warnings 2 and 3). These warning messages didn't pop up on the earlier version of R and lme4 I used, so it must have something to do with latest updates?

A subset of my dataset:

```
    df <- structure(list(SUR.ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("10185", "10186", "10250"), class = "factor"), 
    tm = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("CT", "PT-04"), class = "factor"), ValidDetections = c(0L, 
    0L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 23L, 
    21L, 15L, 28L, 11L, 27L, 22L, 31L, 29L, 30L, 32L, 45L, 18L, 
    19L, 29L, 26L, 32L, 43L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 24L, 22L, 19L, 23L, 21L, 34L, 9L, 13L, 30L, 
    25L, 33L, 21L, 4L, 18L, 22L, 29L, 11L, 38L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 
    6L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 23L, 20L, 24L, 26L, 29L, 
    34L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 6L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 21L, 12L, 
    15L, 8L, 23L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), CountDetections = c(0L, 
    0L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 
    0L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 23L, 
    21L, 18L, 28L, 11L, 27L, 23L, 31L, 29L, 30L, 34L, 45L, 19L, 
    19L, 29L, 26L, 32L, 43L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 24L, 22L, 19L, 23L, 21L, 34L, 10L, 15L, 30L, 
    25L, 34L, 24L, 4L, 19L, 23L, 29L, 13L, 38L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 
    7L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 23L, 20L, 24L, 26L, 29L, 
    34L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 1L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
    0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 
    3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 23L, 12L, 
    16L, 10L, 23L, 10L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), FalseDetections = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
    0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
    0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), replicate = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
    Area = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("Drug Channel", "Finger"), class = "factor"), 
    Day = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L
    ), .Label = c("03/06/13", "2/22/13", "2/26/13", "2/27/13", 
    "3/14/13"), class = "factor"), R.det = c(0, 0, 0.857142857, 
    1, 0.333333333, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0.875, 0.75, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0.666666667, 0.333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0.75, 1, 1, 0.8, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0.857142857, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 1, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0.833333333, 
    1, 1, 1, 0.956521739, 1, 1, 1, 0.941176471, 1, 0.947368421, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 0.9, 0.866666667, 1, 1, 0.970588235, 0.875, 1, 
    0.947368421, 0.956521739, 1, 0.846153846, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    0.857142857, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.75, 0, 1, 0.857142857, 0, 0, 0, 0.333333333, 
    0.5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.666666667, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0.6, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.666666667, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0.666666667, 0, 0, 0, 0.666666667, 0, 0.666666667, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.666666667, 1, 1, 1, 0.857142857, 0.5, 
    0.6, 0, 0, 0.333333333, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0.913043478, 1, 0.9375, 0.8, 1, 0.7, 1, 1, 1, 1), c.receiver.depth = c(-0.2, 
    -0.2, -0.2, -0.2, -0.2, -0.2, -0.22, -0.22, -0.22, -0.22, 
    -0.22, -0.22, -0.22, -0.22, -0.22, -0.22, -0.22, -0.22, -0.225, 
    -0.225, -0.225, -0.225, -0.225, -0.225, -0.225, -0.225, -0.225, 
    -0.225, -0.225, -0.225, -0.205, -0.205, -0.205, -0.205, -0.205, 
    -0.205, -0.185, -0.185, -0.185, -0.185, -0.185, -0.185, -0.18, 
    -0.18, -0.18, -0.18, -0.18, -0.18, -0.165, -0.165, -0.165, 
    -0.165, -0.165, -0.165, -0.14, -0.14, -0.14, -0.14, -0.14, 
    -0.14, -0.34, -0.34, -0.34, -0.34, -0.34, -0.34, -0.365, 
    -0.365, -0.365, -0.365, -0.365, -0.365, -0.365, -0.365, -0.365, 
    -0.365, -0.365, -0.365, -0.38, -0.38, -0.38, -0.38, -0.38, 
    -0.38, -0.385, -0.385, -0.385, -0.385, -0.385, -0.385, -0.395, 
    -0.395, -0.395, -0.395, -0.395, -0.395, -0.4, -0.4, -0.4, 
    -0.4, -0.4, -0.4, -0.395, -0.395, -0.395, -0.395, -0.395, 
    -0.395, -0.38, -0.38, -0.38, -0.38, -0.38, -0.38, -0.37, 
    -0.37, -0.37, -0.37, -0.37, -0.37, -0.285, -0.285, -0.285, 
    -0.285, -0.285, -0.285, -0.31, -0.31, -0.31, -0.31, -0.31, 
    -0.31, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.225, 0.225, 
    0.225, 0.225, 0.225, 0.225, 0.225, 0.225, 0.225, 0.225, 0.225, 
    0.225, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.185, 0.185, 
    0.185, 0.185, 0.185, 0.185, 0.175, 0.175, 0.175, 0.175, 0.175, 
    0.175, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 
    0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.105, 0.105, 0.105, 0.105, 0.105, 0.105, 
    0.215, 0.215, 0.215, 0.215, 0.215, 0.215, 0.54, 0.54, 0.54, 
    0.54, 0.54, 0.54, 0.525, 0.525, 0.525, 0.525, 0.525, 0.525, 
    0.515, 0.515, 0.515, 0.515, 0.515, 0.515, 0.545, 0.545, 0.545, 
    0.545, 0.545, 0.545, 0.525, 0.525, 0.525, 0.525), c.tm.depth = c(0.042807692, 
    0.042807692, 0.042807692, 0.042807692, 0.042807692, 0.042807692, 
    -0.282192308, -0.282192308, -0.282192308, -0.282192308, -0.282192308, 
    -0.282192308, -0.427192308, -0.427192308, -0.427192308, -0.427192308, 
    -0.427192308, -0.427192308, -0.027192308, -0.027192308, -0.027192308, 
    -0.027192308, -0.027192308, -0.027192308, 0.022807692, 0.022807692, 
    0.022807692, 0.022807692, 0.022807692, 0.022807692, 0.042807692, 
    0.042807692, 0.042807692, 0.042807692, 0.042807692, 0.042807692, 
    -0.267192308, -0.267192308, -0.267192308, -0.267192308, -0.267192308, 
    -0.267192308, -0.312192308, -0.312192308, -0.312192308, -0.312192308, 
    -0.312192308, -0.312192308, 0.062807692, 0.062807692, 0.062807692, 
    0.062807692, 0.062807692, 0.062807692, 0.127807692, 0.127807692, 
    0.127807692, 0.127807692, 0.127807692, 0.127807692, -0.592192308, 
    -0.592192308, -0.592192308, -0.592192308, -0.592192308, -0.592192308, 
    -0.612192308, -0.612192308, -0.612192308, -0.612192308, -0.612192308, 
    -0.612192308, -0.597192308, -0.597192308, -0.597192308, -0.597192308, 
    -0.597192308, -0.597192308, -0.607192308, -0.607192308, -0.607192308, 
    -0.607192308, -0.607192308, -0.607192308, -0.327192308, -0.327192308, 
    -0.327192308, -0.327192308, -0.327192308, -0.327192308, -0.572192308, 
    -0.572192308, -0.572192308, -0.572192308, -0.572192308, -0.572192308, 
    -0.622192308, -0.622192308, -0.622192308, -0.622192308, -0.622192308, 
    -0.622192308, -0.572192308, -0.572192308, -0.572192308, -0.572192308, 
    -0.572192308, -0.572192308, -0.577192308, -0.577192308, -0.577192308, 
    -0.577192308, -0.577192308, -0.577192308, -0.272192308, -0.272192308, 
    -0.272192308, -0.272192308, -0.272192308, -0.272192308, -0.547192308, 
    -0.547192308, -0.547192308, -0.547192308, -0.547192308, -0.547192308, 
    -0.607192308, -0.607192308, -0.607192308, -0.607192308, -0.607192308, 
    -0.607192308, 0.552807692, 0.552807692, 0.552807692, 0.552807692, 
    0.552807692, 0.552807692, 0.402807692, 0.402807692, 0.402807692, 
    0.402807692, 0.402807692, 0.402807692, 0.777807692, 0.777807692, 
    0.777807692, 0.777807692, 0.777807692, 0.777807692, 0.752807692, 
    0.752807692, 0.752807692, 0.752807692, 0.752807692, 0.752807692, 
    0.752807692, 0.752807692, 0.752807692, 0.752807692, 0.752807692, 
    0.752807692, 0.402807692, 0.402807692, 0.402807692, 0.402807692, 
    0.402807692, 0.402807692, 0.292807692, 0.292807692, 0.292807692, 
    0.292807692, 0.292807692, 0.292807692, 0.667807692, 0.667807692, 
    0.667807692, 0.667807692, 0.667807692, 0.667807692, 0.677807692, 
    0.677807692, 0.677807692, 0.677807692, 0.677807692, 0.677807692, 
    0.777807692, 0.777807692, 0.777807692, 0.777807692, 0.777807692, 
    0.777807692, 0.252807692, 0.252807692, 0.252807692, 0.252807692, 
    0.252807692, 0.252807692, 0.352807692, 0.352807692, 0.352807692, 
    0.352807692, 0.352807692, 0.352807692, 0.502807692, 0.502807692, 
    0.502807692, 0.502807692, 0.502807692, 0.502807692, 0.027807692, 
    0.027807692, 0.027807692, 0.027807692, 0.027807692, 0.027807692, 
    0.077807692, 0.077807692, 0.077807692, 0.077807692), c.temp = c(-4.095807692, 
    -4.095807692, -4.095807692, -4.095807692, -4.095807692, -4.095807692, 
    -4.220807692, -4.220807692, -4.220807692, -4.220807692, -4.220807692, 
    -4.220807692, -4.210807692, -4.210807692, -4.210807692, -4.210807692, 
    -4.210807692, -4.210807692, -4.175807692, -4.175807692, -4.175807692, 
    -4.175807692, -4.175807692, -4.175807692, -4.035807692, -4.035807692, 
    -4.035807692, -4.035807692, -4.035807692, -4.035807692, -3.920807692, 
    -3.920807692, -3.920807692, -3.920807692, -3.920807692, -3.920807692, 
    -3.820807692, -3.820807692, -3.820807692, -3.820807692, -3.820807692, 
    -3.820807692, -3.640807692, -3.640807692, -3.640807692, -3.640807692, 
    -3.640807692, -3.640807692, -3.660807692, -3.660807692, -3.660807692, 
    -3.660807692, -3.660807692, -3.660807692, -3.620807692, -3.620807692, 
    -3.620807692, -3.620807692, -3.620807692, -3.620807692, 0.074192308, 
    0.074192308, 0.074192308, 0.074192308, 0.074192308, 0.074192308, 
    -0.015807692, -0.015807692, -0.015807692, -0.015807692, -0.015807692, 
    -0.015807692, 0.324192308, 0.324192308, 0.324192308, 0.324192308, 
    0.324192308, 0.324192308, 0.544192308, 0.544192308, 0.544192308, 
    0.544192308, 0.544192308, 0.544192308, 0.759192308, 0.759192308, 
    0.759192308, 0.759192308, 0.759192308, 0.759192308, 1.324192308, 
    1.324192308, 1.324192308, 1.324192308, 1.324192308, 1.324192308, 
    1.549192308, 1.549192308, 1.549192308, 1.549192308, 1.549192308, 
    1.549192308, 1.709192308, 1.709192308, 1.709192308, 1.709192308, 
    1.709192308, 1.709192308, 1.639192308, 1.639192308, 1.639192308, 
    1.639192308, 1.639192308, 1.639192308, 1.579192308, 1.579192308, 
    1.579192308, 1.579192308, 1.579192308, 1.579192308, 2.724192308, 
    2.724192308, 2.724192308, 2.724192308, 2.724192308, 2.724192308, 
    2.839192308, 2.839192308, 2.839192308, 2.839192308, 2.839192308, 
    2.839192308, 1.064192308, 1.064192308, 1.064192308, 1.064192308, 
    1.064192308, 1.064192308, 1.184192308, 1.184192308, 1.184192308, 
    1.184192308, 1.184192308, 1.184192308, 1.254192308, 1.254192308, 
    1.254192308, 1.254192308, 1.254192308, 1.254192308, 1.379192308, 
    1.379192308, 1.379192308, 1.379192308, 1.379192308, 1.379192308, 
    1.529192308, 1.529192308, 1.529192308, 1.529192308, 1.529192308, 
    1.529192308, 1.599192308, 1.599192308, 1.599192308, 1.599192308, 
    1.599192308, 1.599192308, 1.669192308, 1.669192308, 1.669192308, 
    1.669192308, 1.669192308, 1.669192308, 1.664192308, 1.664192308, 
    1.664192308, 1.664192308, 1.664192308, 1.664192308, 1.714192308, 
    1.714192308, 1.714192308, 1.714192308, 1.714192308, 1.714192308, 
    0.984192308, 0.984192308, 0.984192308, 0.984192308, 0.984192308, 
    0.984192308, -1.545807692, -1.545807692, -1.545807692, -1.545807692, 
    -1.545807692, -1.545807692, -1.475807692, -1.475807692, -1.475807692, 
    -1.475807692, -1.475807692, -1.475807692, -1.460807692, -1.460807692, 
    -1.460807692, -1.460807692, -1.460807692, -1.460807692, -1.340807692, 
    -1.340807692, -1.340807692, -1.340807692, -1.340807692, -1.340807692, 
    -1.265807692, -1.265807692, -1.265807692, -1.265807692), 
    c.wind = c(1.27535159, 1.27535159, 1.27535159, 1.27535159, 
    1.27535159, 1.27535159, 1.27535159, 1.27535159, 1.27535159, 
    1.27535159, 1.27535159, 1.27535159, 1.27535159, 1.27535159, 
    1.27535159, 1.27535159, 1.27535159, 1.27535159, 1.27535159, 
    1.27535159, 1.27535159, 1.27535159, 1.27535159, 1.27535159, 
    1.27535159, 1.27535159, 1.27535159, 1.27535159, 1.27535159, 
    1.27535159, 1.27535159, 1.27535159, 1.27535159, 1.27535159, 
    1.27535159, 1.27535159, 1.27535159, 1.27535159, 1.27535159, 
    1.27535159, 1.27535159, 1.27535159, 1.27535159, 1.27535159, 
    1.27535159, 1.27535159, 1.27535159, 1.27535159, 1.27535159, 
    1.27535159, 1.27535159, 1.27535159, 1.27535159, 1.27535159, 
    1.27535159, 1.27535159, 1.27535159, 1.27535159, 1.27535159, 
    1.27535159, -2.96855001, -2.96855001, -2.96855001, -2.96855001, 
    -2.96855001, -2.96855001, -2.96855001, -2.96855001, -2.96855001, 
    -2.96855001, -2.96855001, -2.96855001, -2.96855001, -2.96855001, 
    -2.96855001, -2.96855001, -2.96855001, -2.96855001, -2.96855001, 
    -2.96855001, -2.96855001, -2.96855001, -2.96855001, -2.96855001, 
    -2.96855001, -2.96855001, -2.96855001, -2.96855001, -2.96855001, 
    -2.96855001, -2.96855001, -2.96855001, -2.96855001, -2.96855001, 
    -2.96855001, -2.96855001, -2.96855001, -2.96855001, -2.96855001, 
    -2.96855001, -2.96855001, -2.96855001, -2.96855001, -2.96855001, 
    -2.96855001, -2.96855001, -2.96855001, -2.96855001, -2.96855001, 
    -2.96855001, -2.96855001, -2.96855001, -2.96855001, -2.96855001, 
    -2.96855001, -2.96855001, -2.96855001, -2.96855001, -2.96855001, 
    -2.96855001, 4.71144999, 4.71144999, 4.71144999, 4.71144999, 
    4.71144999, 4.71144999, 4.71144999, 4.71144999, 4.71144999, 
    4.71144999, 4.71144999, 4.71144999, -2.939182972, -2.939182972, 
    -2.939182972, -2.939182972, -2.939182972, -2.939182972, -2.939182972, 
    -2.939182972, -2.939182972, -2.939182972, -2.939182972, -2.939182972, 
    -2.939182972, -2.939182972, -2.939182972, -2.939182972, -2.939182972, 
    -2.939182972, -2.939182972, -2.939182972, -2.939182972, -2.939182972, 
    -2.939182972, -2.939182972, -2.939182972, -2.939182972, -2.939182972, 
    -2.939182972, -2.939182972, -2.939182972, -2.939182972, -2.939182972, 
    -2.939182972, -2.939182972, -2.939182972, -2.939182972, -2.939182972, 
    -2.939182972, -2.939182972, -2.939182972, -2.939182972, -2.939182972, 
    -2.939182972, -2.939182972, -2.939182972, -2.939182972, -2.939182972, 
    -2.939182972, -2.939182972, -2.939182972, -2.939182972, -2.939182972, 
    -2.939182972, -2.939182972, -2.939182972, -2.939182972, -2.939182972, 
    -2.939182972, -2.939182972, -2.939182972, 5.88092439, 5.88092439, 
    5.88092439, 5.88092439, 5.88092439, 5.88092439, 5.88092439, 
    5.88092439, 5.88092439, 5.88092439, 5.88092439, 5.88092439, 
    5.88092439, 5.88092439, 5.88092439, 5.88092439, 5.88092439, 
    5.88092439, 5.88092439, 5.88092439, 5.88092439, 5.88092439, 
    5.88092439, 5.88092439, 5.88092439, 5.88092439, 5.88092439, 
    5.88092439), c.distance = c(-160L, -160L, -160L, -160L, -160L, 
    -160L, -110L, -110L, -110L, -110L, -110L, -110L, -10L, -10L, 
    -10L, -10L, -10L, -10L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 190L, 
    190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, -160L, -160L, -160L, -160L, 
    -160L, -160L, -110L, -110L, -110L, -110L, -110L, -110L, -10L, 
    -10L, -10L, -10L, -10L, -10L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 
    190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, -160L, -160L, -160L, 
    -160L, -160L, -160L, -110L, -110L, -110L, -110L, -110L, -110L, 
    -10L, -10L, -10L, -10L, -10L, -10L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 
    90L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, -160L, -160L, -160L, 
    -160L, -160L, -160L, -110L, -110L, -110L, -110L, -110L, -110L, 
    -10L, -10L, -10L, -10L, -10L, -10L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 
    90L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, -160L, -160L, -160L, 
    -160L, -160L, -160L, -110L, -110L, -110L, -110L, -110L, -110L, 
    -110L, -110L, -110L, -110L, -110L, -110L, -10L, -10L, -10L, 
    -10L, -10L, -10L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 190L, 190L, 
    190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, -160L, -160L, -160L, -160L, -160L, 
    -160L, -110L, -110L, -110L, -110L, -110L, -110L, -10L, -10L, 
    -10L, -10L, -10L, -10L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 190L, 
    190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, -160L, -160L, -160L, -160L, 
    -160L, -160L, -10L, -10L, -10L, -10L, -10L, -10L, 90L, 90L, 
    90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, -160L, 
    -160L, -160L, -160L, -160L, -160L, -110L, -110L, -110L, -110L
    )), .Names = c("SUR.ID", "tm", "ValidDetections", "CountDetections", 
"FalseDetections", "replicate", "Area", "Day", "R.det", "c.receiver.depth", 
"c.tm.depth", "c.temp", "c.wind", "c.distance"), row.names = c(NA, 
-220L), class = "data.frame")
```

My script:

```
library(lme4)
df$SUR.ID <- factor(df$SUR.ID)
df$replicate <- factor(df$replicate)
Rdet <- cbind(df$ValidDetections,df$FalseDetections)
Unit <- factor(1:length(df$ValidDetections))
m1 <- glmer(Rdet ~ tm:Area + tm:c.distance + c.distance:Area + c.tm.depth:Area + c.receiver.depth:Area + c.temp:Area + c.wind:Area + c.tm.depth + c.receiver.depth + c.temp +c.wind + tm + c.distance + Area + replicate + (1|SUR.ID) + (1|Day) + (1|Unit) , data = df, family = binomial(link=logit))
```

(Unit = dispersion parameter used to calculate coefficients of determination)

In contrast to early 2013, the newest versions of R and lme4 return the following 3 warning messages:

```
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 62.5817 (tol = 0.001)
2: In if (resHess$code != 0) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
 - Rescale variables?;Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio
 - Rescale variables?
```

I searched google and stack overflow for potential solutions to the above warning messages, however I cannot make sense out of them, and how it may be applied to my specific model / data.

Subsequently, I'm trying to find the MAM by using the drop1() function in R using a Chi^2 test and remove non-significant variables 1 at a time. Ignoring the above warning messages, I execute the following command:

```
drop1(m1,test="Chi")
```

However, this command cannot be used (i.e., returns addition warning messages) if the above warnings are not solved / dealt with first.

Does anyone know what is happening here? Please, can someone help me how to solve these warnings? Ignoring is not an option.

Comment: can you try the version from Github (`library(devtools); install_github("lme4","lme4")` and see if this resolves your convergence warnings?

Comment: @Ben, thank you for your reply. I just installed devtools and tried to install github. However, I get the following error messages:
'* preparing 'lme4':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* cleaning src
* installing the package to build vignettes
* creating vignettes ... ERROR
Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
  Running 'texi2dvi' on 'PLSvGLS.tex' failed.
Calls: <Anonymous> -> texi2pdf -> texi2dvi
Execution halted
Error: Command failed (1)'

Comment: not sure why it happens.  What OS are you on?  I can build a current binary version and post it at http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org .  I have been working on your example; I still see some issues that I'm trying to work out.

Comment: @BenBolker, I'm running on Mac OS X Mavericks. Thanks for your efforts, really appreciated.

Comment: hmm.  I'll do a MacOS binary build, but I'm still on a pre-Mavericks version and don't know if there are compatibility issues.

Comment: MacOS binaries (built under R 3.1/OS X 10.6.8) pushed to `http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/repos`; they'll show up there in <24 hours. If you're in a hurry you can get them from `https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/www/repos/bin/macosx/contrib/3.1/?root=lme4`

Comment: @BenBolker: I managed to DL the binaries. I tried every combination of R (Snow Leopard and higher & Mavericks & higher) and lme4 (4.0, 4.1.1.6 and 4.1.1.7), but the warnings / errors persist. However, with the combination R (OSX SL and higher) and lme4.0.99 I get error message "downdated X'X is not positive definite, 1", even with null (slope only) model. In this case, no collinearity is present.

Comment: I've run into a very similar issue: an old model from February 2013 that I'm trying to rerun. I get the same first warning message `In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 1.09141 (tol = 0.001)` It had no issue back in February 2013.

Comment: Apparently you can safely ignore these issues. Please see Ben Bolker's replies at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21344555/convergence-error-for-development-version-of-lme4 for more details.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**tl;dr** at least based on the subset of data you provided, this is a fairly unstable fit.  The warnings about near unidentifiability go away if you scale the continuous predictors.  Trying with a wide variety of optimizers, we get about the same log-likelihoods, and parameter estimates that vary by a few percent; two optimizers (`nlminb` from base R and BOBYQA from the `nloptr` package) converge without warnings, and are probably giving the "correct" answer.  I haven't computed confidence intervals, but I suspect that they're very wide.  (Your mileage may differ somewhat with your full data set ...)

```
source("SO_23478792_dat.R")  ## I put the data you provided in here
```

Basic fit (replicated from above):

```
library(lme4)
df$SUR.ID <- factor(df$SUR.ID)
df$replicate <- factor(df$replicate)
Rdet <- cbind(df$ValidDetections,df$FalseDetections)
Unit <- factor(1:length(df$ValidDetections))
m1 <- glmer(Rdet ~ tm:Area + tm:c.distance +
            c.distance:Area + c.tm.depth:Area +
            c.receiver.depth:Area + c.temp:Area +
            c.wind:Area +
            c.tm.depth + c.receiver.depth +
            c.temp +c.wind + tm + c.distance + Area +
            replicate +
            (1|SUR.ID) + (1|Day) + (1|Unit) ,
            data = df, family = binomial(link=logit))
```

I get more or less the same warnings you did, slightly fewer since the development version has been a little improved/tweaked:

```
## 1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
##   Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 1.52673 (tol = 0.001, component 1)
## 2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
##   Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
##  - Rescale variables?;Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio
## - Rescale variables?
```

I tried various little things (restarting from the previous fitted values, switching optimizers) without much change in the results (i.e. the same warnings).

```
ss <- getME(m1,c("theta","fixef"))
m2 <- update(m1,start=ss,control=glmerControl(optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e4)))
m3 <- update(m1,start=ss,control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa",
                         optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e4)))
```

Following the advice in the warning message (rescaling the continuous predictors):

```
numcols <- grep("^c\\.",names(df))
dfs <- df
dfs[,numcols] <- scale(dfs[,numcols])
m4 <- update(m1,data=dfs)
```

This gets rid of scaling warnings, but the warning about large gradients persists.

Use some utility code to fit the same model with many different optimizers:

```
afurl <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lme4/lme4/master/misc/issues/allFit.R"
## http://tonybreyal.wordpress.com/2011/11/24/source_https-sourcing-an-r-script-from-github/
library(RCurl)
eval(parse(text=getURL(afurl)))
aa <- allFit(m4)
is.OK <- sapply(aa,is,"merMod")  ## nlopt NELDERMEAD failed, others succeeded
## extract just the successful ones
aa.OK <- aa[is.OK]
```

Pull out warnings:

```
lapply(aa.OK,function(x) x@optinfo$conv$lme4$messages)
```

(All but `nlminb` and nloptr BOBYQA give convergence warnings.)

Log-likelihoods are all approximately the same:

```
summary(sapply(aa.OK,logLik),digits=6)
##     Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
## -107.127 -107.114 -107.111 -107.114 -107.110 -107.110
```

(again, `nlminb` and nloptr BOBYQA have the best fits/highest log-likelihoods)

Compare fixed effect parameters across optimizers:

```
aa.fixef <- t(sapply(aa.OK,fixef))
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)
aa.fixef.m <- melt(aa.fixef)
models <- levels(aa.fixef.m$Var1)
(gplot1 <- ggplot(aa.fixef.m,aes(x=value,y=Var1,colour=Var1))+geom_point()+
    facet_wrap(~Var2,scale="free")+
    scale_y_discrete(breaks=models,
                     labels=abbreviate(models,6)))
## coefficients of variation of fixed-effect parameter estimates:
summary(unlist(daply(aa.fixef.m,"Var2",summarise,sd(value)/abs(mean(value)))))
##     Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
## 0.003573 0.013300 0.022730 0.019710 0.026200 0.035810
```

Compare variance estimates (not as interesting: all optimizers except N-M give exactly
zero variance for Day and SUR.ID)

```
aa.varcorr <- t(sapply(aa.OK,function(x) unlist(VarCorr(x))))
aa.varcorr.m <- melt(aa.varcorr)
gplot1 %+% aa.varcorr.m
```

I tried to run this with `lme4.0` ("old lme4"), but got various "Downdated VtV" errors, even with the scaled data set.  Perhaps that problem would go away with the full data set?

I haven't yet explored why `drop1` doesn't work properly if the initial fit returns warnings ...

Comment: Unfortunately the Downdated X'X errors(?)(under R OSX SL and higher) do not go away when using the older lme4 version on the full dataset. On a side note: I managed to install OSX Snow Leopard on another drive, using R v2.14 and v2.15 in combination with the old lme4 package. Strangely enough, that combination does work - does not produce errors. Also, I had my script ran on a windows pc, and no errors occurred. So my bet is that it has something to do with running from OSX Mavericks that causes these errors, regardless which R version you use (Snow Leopard or higher OR Mavericks or higher)

Comment: Hmm.  Is there any chance you can send the data (to be shared only with me and one of my co-workers who has Mavericks installed)?

Comment: On a side note: I tried to run old lme4 on R for mavericks and higher, and got returned the following error message:
Loading required package: Matrix
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...): 
  unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/lme4.0/libs/lme4.so':
 dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/lme4.0/libs/lme4.so, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgfortran.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/[..]Reason: image not found
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘lme4.0’

Comment: Hi @BenBolker; I am receiving similar messages on rescaling variables / large eigenvalue. Messages persist on rescaling & different optimisers. There is not a huge difference in fixed effects & log-likelihood between different optimiser models. Are the effects of these potentially problematic (I cant find anything about this). Thanks.

Comment: if the answers are sufficiently similar across optimizers that none of your conclusions change, then I'd say you're OK.