# Unscale and uncenter glmer standard errors

Tags: r, lme4, rescale

As a follow up to this question [unscale and uncenter glmer parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24268031/unscale-and-uncenter-glmer-parameters/24286763#24286763), how can I unscale and uncenter glmer standard errors?

Could someone provide a function similar to rescale.coefs but for standard errors?
If needed, the question referred to above includes an example.

Comment: You should offer a particular data-situation. And since it really does look trivial you should indicate what difficulty you are having with understanding how to "unscale" a value. The scaled vectors will have the necessary information in their attributes. Read `?scale` before responding.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it is not simply a matter of undoing `scale` but of understanding how to "re-adjust" the standard errors of scaled regressors.

Comment: Then it's really not a well specified coding problem yet, and you should seek appropriate statistical advice.

Comment: Clarification: it is very simple to un-standardize (reverse the centering and scaling of) the standard errors of the parameter estimates. I am just struggling with the the un-standardization of the standard error of the intercept. Thanks.

Comment: @BondedDust As you suggested, I asked a similar question on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179281/determine-the-original-standard-error-of-the-intercept-in-a-regression-estimated)