# Convergence error on lme4

Tags: r, lme4

The model that I tried to specify was:

```
M4 <- glmer(CORT_pgmm~AO_Ause+(1|St),data=belcher,family=Gamma(link="log"), control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"))
```

While doing this I got the following warning message using *glmer* with "`bobyqa"` and `"Nelder_Mead"` as optimizers.

```
Warning message:
In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.0146734 (tol = 0.001, component 1)
```

I followed the instructions given by Mr. Ben Bolker in a previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21344555/convergence-error-for-development-version-of-lme4)

Once I change the optimizers to the ones contained in the `optimx` package the warning message stop appearing.

```
 M4 <- glmer(CORT_pgmm~AO_Ause+(1|St),data=belcher,family=Gamma(link="log"), control=glmerControl(optimizer="optimx",optCtrl=list(method="nlminb")))
```

Still, I am not sure how to know if this is the correct way to proceed in my case. How can I be sure about it?

My apologies if I did not write this correctly as it is my first post. Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: I'll let BenBolker respond here, but it is generally helpful to provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can never be sure (this is numerical optimization of a case about which we can't prove a whole lot in the general case), but as a general matter I would say that if you have **succeeded in reaching approximately the same putatively "optimal" parameter estimates with more than one different optimizer** (e.g. using `allFit()`) you can stop worrying about convergence failure. How close "approximately" is depends on personal taste and scientific goals. For my typical use cases, estimating parameters within (say) 1%, or conservatively 0.1%, of each other with different optimizers would count as "approximately equal".

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It was really helpful.